# How to display dates using prompts in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prompt

I am trying to insert dates in the prompt boxes using JavaScript. How do I do it?
I have tried to insert month and date using prompt window separately using two prompt windows.

Comment: Please show what you're trying to do.

Comment: `prompt('Today is: ',new Date());`

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you asking how to prompt for a date value, or are you asking how to show a prompt with the current date as default value listed in the prompt?

Answer (score 1):

[JavaScript prompt method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) accepts strings as input. You can use the date object, perform some string formatting and pass it to the prompt object and it should work as shown below:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/322zp/2/)

**JavaScript:**

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
function myFunction() {
    var today = new Date();
    var date = prompt("Please enter date.", today.getDate()+"-"+monthNames[today.getMonth()]+"-"+today.getFullYear());

    if (date != null) {
        x = "Hello! You have entered date as: " + date;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
}
```